# BLE Read characteristics takes approximately takes 3 to 4 seconds? How to read faster?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

We do a BLE based iOS and android application. Our process was write data to BLE device after write success(didWriteValueFor characteristic), we call read data using characteristic. Every command was working. Now we do OTA update in firmware. In this case we send every 120 bytes data to BLE device, after write success it reads data and verify and send to another packet. we see 4 seconds Timing for one chunk of data write and read for validation. Is it possible to read data faster?

**Step1 (cData=120bytes):**

blePeripheral.writeValue(cData, for: WCharateristics,
type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)

**Step2 after write success this delegate fired:**

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)

**Step3 didWriteValueFor we called read to get data from BLE device:**

centralPeripheral.readValue(for: readCharateristics)

**Step4 read data Response from BLE:**

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)

Write success takes 2 seconds to reach step2, like read success takes 2 seconds to reach step4.

I also tried one more method, After write data i am immediately called read Characteristic after 200 ms delay. But still the data receive takes 4 seconds to get data. In android application it works faster.

I don't want to use BLE write using without response, because i need to verify every packets i sent was correct or not by verify with read function.

Please guide me thanks.

Comment: Why do you need an extra read? The write response indicates "no error". Otherwise you would receive an error code instead.

Comment: Normally if you read data from BLE device how soon you will get response? like in seconds, or milli seconds.

Comment: It totally depends on the connection interval combined with slave latency. If you have a connection interval of 4 seconds and slave latency = 0, then expect a reply within 4-8 seconds. If you have a connection interval of 12.5 ms, expect a reply within 25 ms.

Comment: @Emil Thanks bro.. Fixed and now its working connection interval have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest look at the connection interval and slave latency settings on the BLE Peripheral.

These timings can be set by the hardware to either increase power usage and increase throughput or decrease power usage and reduce throughput.

For example reducing the connection interval does as follows:

- Increases the power consumption for both devices
- Increases the throughput in both directions
- Reduces the time for sending data in either direction

Increasing the connection interval does as follows:

- Reduces the power consumption for both devices
- Reduces the throughput in both directions
- Increases the time for sending data in either direction

Check out section 41.6 "Connection Parameters" in this document: https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf

Comment: Ok .. We will look that settings in BLE peripheral. Doubt is how our android app can read faster? but iOS can't. Before write I checked MTU size it tells 240 in iOS app.

Comment: Is there anything we need to set in iOS side? Like connection interval and slave latency settings

Comment: The BLE peripheral requests the connection parameters e.g. the interval. The Master can reject these parameters. I don't think you can programmatically change that in iOS or Android (as a Master). It is possible that iOS or Android is rejecting the peripherals request and is defaulting to different connection parameters. Check the interval/connection parameters in the peripherals code.

Comment: we updated connection interval 6ms and latency 10ms. But still iOS app read value takes 4 seconds. Any idea?

Comment: Check out the section 41.6 "Connection Parameters" in the document above. You are outside of the spec for iOS, e.g.: Interval Min of at least 15 ms.
●
Interval Min is a multiple of 15 ms.

Comment: Thanks bro.. Fixed and now its working connection interval have problems.